# Why is it disregarding the code?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make an "animation" for the start of my game, but as my code goes on it is starting to feel unresponsive to change that I make. For instance, even if I make ML = 99999999 instead of starting over at ML = 1, it will still reset the animation. This makes no sense to me. Please help and thanks in advance.

```
    elif V == 4:
        if event.type == event_250ms:
            if ML == 1:
                D.fill(MEXON)
                x_coord = 0
                y_coord = 0
                direction = 'up'
                B(LLCN1, (40, 140))
                B(LLCS1, (400, 240))
                ML = 2
            elif ML == 2:
                D.fill(MEXON)
                x_coord = 0
                y_coord = 0
                direction = 'up'
                B(LLCN2, (41, 140))
                B(LLCS2, (399, 240))
                ML = 3
            elif ML == 3:
                D.fill(MEXON)
                x_coord = 0
                y_coord = 0
                direction = 'up'
                B(LLCN3, (42, 140))
                B(LLCS3, (398, 240))
                ML = 4
            elif ML == 4:
                D.fill(MEXON)
                x_coord = 0
                y_coord = 0
                direction = 'up'
                B(LLCN4, (43, 140))
                B(LLCS4, (397, 240))
                ML = 5
            elif ML == 5:
                D.fill(MEXON)
                x_coord = 0
                y_coord = 0
                direction = 'up'
                B(LLCN5, (44, 140))
                B(LLCS5, (396, 240))
                ML = 6
            elif ML == 6:
                D.fill(MEXON)
                x_coord = 0
                y_coord = 0
                direction = 'up'
                B(LLCN6, (45, 140))
                B(LLCS6, (395, 240))
                ML = 7
            elif ML == 7:
                D.fill(MEXON)
                x_coord = 0
                y_coord = 0
                direction = 'up'
                B(LLCN7, (46, 140))
                B(LLCS7, (394, 240))
                ML = 1
            elif ML == 8:
                D.fill(MEXON)
                x_coord = 0
                y_coord = 0
                direction = 'up'
                B(LLCN8, (47, 140))
                B(LLCS8, (393, 240))
                ML = 9
            elif ML == 9:
                D.fill(MEXON)
                x_coord = 0
                y_coord = 0
                direction = 'up'
                B(LLCN9, (48, 140))
                B(LLCS9, (392, 240))
                ML = 10
            elif ML == 10:
                D.fill(MEXON)
                x_coord = 0
                y_coord = 0
                direction = 'up'
                B(LLCN10, (49, 140))
                B(LLCS10, (391, 240))
                ML = 11
            elif ML == 11:
                D.fill(MEXON)
                x_coord = 0
                y_coord = 0
                direction = 'up'
                B(LLCN11, (50, 140))
                B(LLCS11, (390, 240))
                ML = 12
            elif ML == 12:
                D.fill(MEXON)
                x_coord = 0
                y_coord = 0
                direction = 'up'
                B(LLCN12, (51, 140))
                B(LLCS12, (389, 240))
                ML = 1
```

This is the code for the animation in question. Next is the part where I declare all of the statements and such.

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

BLACK =          (  0,   0,   0)
PINDLER =        (255, 123,  90)
MEXON =          (200, 180, 220)
WHITE =          (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW =         (255, 255,   0)
RED =            (255,   0,   0)
BLUE =           (  0,   0, 255)

size = [700, 500]
D = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
L = pygame.draw.aaline
R = pygame.draw.rect
G = random.randrange(1, 10)
GM = 1
GMT = 2
CIP = 1
SH = 0
AAC = 2
CHBP = 0
STHB = 1
CC = 0
CM = 1
PL = pygame.draw.line
PE = pygame.draw.ellipse
GMFT = 0
HTT = 0
CO = 2
V = 5
ML = 1
PFO = 0
CL = 0
Blue = 1
Red = 1
LEVEL = 1
event_250ms = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(event_250ms, 250)

pygame.display.set_caption("Moline")
myfont1 = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 40)
myfont2 = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 60)
myfont3 = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 20)
myfont4 = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 100)
T1 = myfont1.render
T2 = myfont2.render
T3 = myfont3.render
T4 = myfont4.render
MOL = "MOLINE"
M1S = "DIRECTIONS:"
M2S = "1. Use the arrow keys to control the four characters"
M2F = " off of the track to move them."
M3S = "2. To win a level, line up the four characters on"
M3F = " the crossmark before the runner on the track"
M3C = " reaches the finish line."
M4S = "3. If the runner reaches the finish line, then"
M4F = " you lose."
M5S = "4. When you lose you go back to level one. There"
M5F = " are eight levels."
M6S = "5. Key input makes the runner move slightly"
M6F = " faster, but he will move without input."
M6C = " Additionally, mouse movement makes him even faster."
M7S = "6. It should be noted that whenever you click to"
M7F = " start, the game will immediately begin so have"
M7C = " your arrow keys ready to go."
ISC = "Left-Click to Start Game"
LEST = "Level: "
LU1 = "1"
LU2 = "2"
LU3 = "3"
LU4 = "4"
LU5 = "5"
LU6 = "6"
LU7 = "7"
LU8 = "8"
VTC2 = "Left-Click To Begin Next Level"
VTC3 = "Left-Click To Start Over"
VTC1 = "Left-Click to Start Over"
VT3 = "YOU WIN!!!"
VT2 = "LEVEL COMPLETE"
VT1 = "GAME OVER"
LCN = "Titancorp"
LCS = "Studios"
LCP = "Presents"
LLCS1 = T2(LCS, 1, (200, 180, 220))
LLCS2 = T2(LCS, 1, (205, 187, 200))
LLCS3 = T2(LCS, 1, (210, 194, 180))
LLCS4 = T2(LCS, 1, (215, 201, 160))
LLCS5 = T2(LCS, 1, (220, 208, 140))
LLCS6 = T2(LCS, 1, (225, 215, 120))
LLCS7 = T2(LCS, 1, (230, 222, 100))
LLCS8 = T2(LCS, 1, (235, 229,  80))
LLCS9 = T2(LCS, 1, (240, 236,  60))
LLCS10 = T2(LCS, 1, (245, 243,  40))
LLCS11 = T2(LCS, 1, (250, 250,  20))
LLCS12 = T2(LCS, 1, (255, 255,   0))



LLCN1 = T2(LCN, 1, (200, 180, 220))
LLCN2 = T2(LCN, 1, (205, 187, 200))
LLCN3 = T2(LCN, 1, (210, 194, 180))
LLCN4 = T2(LCN, 1, (215, 201, 160))
LLCN5 = T2(LCN, 1, (220, 208, 140))
LLCN6 = T2(LCN, 1, (225, 215, 120))
LLCN7 = T2(LCN, 1, (230, 222, 100))
LLCN8 = T2(LCN, 1, (235, 229,  80))
LLCN9 = T2(LCN, 1, (240, 236,  60))
LLCN10 = T2(LCN, 1, (245, 243,  40))
LLCN11 = T2(LCN, 1, (250, 250,  20))
LLCN12 = T2(LCN, 1, (255, 255,   0))



#MOLINE TEXT GOES AT (170, 70)
LLCN10000 = T4(MOL, 1, (255, 255, 0))
LLCN2000 = T4(MOL, 1, (235, 235, 50))
LLCN30000 = T4(MOL, 1, (225, 220, 100))
LLCN4000 = T4(MOL, 1, (215, 205, 200))
LLCN50000 = T4(MOL, 1, (200, 180, 220))
L1 = T3(M1S, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L2 = T3(M2S, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L2C = T3(M2F, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L3 = T3(M3S, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L3C = T3(M3F, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L3F = T3(M3C, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L4 = T3(M4S, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L4C = T3(M4F, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L5 = T3(M5S, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L5C = T3 (M5F, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L6 = T3(M6S, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L6C = T3(M6F, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L6F = T3(M6C, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L7 = T3(M7S, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L7C = T3(M7F, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L7F = T3(M7C, 1, (255, 255, 0))
SFGL = T1(ISC, 1, (255, 255, 0))
LES = T3(LEST, 1, (255, 255, 0))
LAS1 = T3(LU1, 1, (255, 255, 0))
LAS2 = T3(LU2, 1, (255, 255, 0))
LAS3 = T3(LU3, 1, (255, 255, 0))
LAS4 = T3(LU4, 1, (255, 255, 0))
LAS5 = T3(LU5, 1, (255, 255, 0))
LAS6 = T3(LU6, 1, (255, 255, 0))
LAS7 = T3(LU7, 1, (255, 255, 0))
LAS8 = T3(LU8, 1, (255, 255, 0))
V3CB = T3(VTC3, 1, (255, 255,   0))
V3CY = T3(VTC3, 1, (  0,   0, 255))
V2CB = T3(VTC2, 1, (255, 255,   0))
V2CY = T3(VTC2, 1, (  0,   0, 255))
V1CB = T3(VTC1, 1, (  0,   0,   0))
V1CR = T3(VTC1, 1, (255,   0,   0))
V3B = T2(VT3, 1, (255, 255,   0))
V3Y = T2(VT3, 1, (  0,   0,   0))
V2B = T2(VT2, 1, (255, 255,   0))
V2Y = T2(VT2, 1, (  0,   0, 255))
V1R = T2(VT1, 1, (  0,   0,   0))
V1B = T2(VT1, 1, (255,   0,   0))
B = D.blit
Fx = 10
Fy = 10
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the *desired behavior*, a *specific problem or error* and the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my issue. I had a typo in the code where ML = 1 again as opposed to advancing to ML = 8. Additionally, I realize that my question was rather vague so my apologies for that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking why a running program does not reflect the change you make after it started running?  It won't work that way, Python loads the entire script at compile time.  It never looks for changes afterwards.